# Socket.IO server does not respond to emit from Android

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect with my Node.js Socket.IO server via an Android app. The console log shows that the phone connects with the server but when I try to emit a message from Android, the server does not give any output on the log console. I have read through the sample Socket.IO Android app but I am not able to figure out what's the problem...

Below lies my code...

**Client** *Android*

```
mSocket.connect();

private void attemptSend() {

        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject1.put("message","This is a test");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mSocket.emit("test",jsonObject1);
        Log.d("TAG", "Sent");
}
```

**Server** *Node.js*

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {    
console.log('User Connected');

socket.on('test', function(data) {
console.log(data.message)
}

});
```

Comment: Do you see the 'User Connected' console message from the server?  Doesn't `mSocket.connect();` require a server URL?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, the console displays 'User Connected' and that's how I know that the Android devices connects with the server. The server URL has been provided to the Android app. The code that is displayed on SO is a snippet of the entire code. That's why you don't see it here :-)

Comment: Could you be calling `attemptSend` before the `mSocket.connect()` finishes?

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey, so the error was actually in the URL that we supplied the mSocket to connect to. We only needed to supply the server URL to mSocket. Instead the erroneous URL that we supplied was of this format [serverURL]/socket.io/socket.io.js and this was giving us a name space error. The error is fixed now. Regardless, thank you for helping us out :-)

Comment: You might at least edit your question to show the part of the code that caused the problem.  You can then provide your own answer to your question to properly closed this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments under the question, the URL that I used while connecting to the server was erroneous. After fixing the URL, the app started working as expected.